# Auto-generate methods for subclasses

Tags: python, python-3.x, generative-programming

I have a few dozen classes.  Here are two of them:

```
class Class_A(ClassABC):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def from_B(self, b):
        #do stuff

    def from_C(self, c):
        #do stuff

    #...

    def to_B(self):
        rt = Class_B()
        rt.from_A(self)
        return rt

    def to_C(self):
        rt = Class_C()
        rt.from_A(self)
        return rt

    #...

class Class_B(ClassABC):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def from_A(self, a):
        #do stuff

    def from_C(self, c):
        #do stuff

    def to_A(self):
        rt = Class_A()
        rt.from_B(self)
        return rt

    def to_C(self):
        rt = Class_C()
        rt.from_B(self)
        return rt

    #...

 #class Class_C, Class_D, Class_E, etc,
```

and here is the ABC:

```
class ClassABC(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def __init__(self):
        #do stuff
```

The problem I have is that all the `to_*` methods in the subclasses follow the same exact pattern, and it becomes tedious to implement them.  I would like to automatically generate them in the `ClassABC` if possible, but so far I have failed.  I also tried creating a class decorater for the subclasses, but that didn't work either.  I have, however, managed to auto generate the methods in each subclass using exec(), but I rather have the ABC generate them or use class decoraters.  Is there a way to do this?

Note: all the classes are in their own separate module

Comment: maybe renaming `from_A` and `from_B` to something like `from_self` could make it easier. You can have a dict just like `{'A': Class_A, 'B': Class_B}` to help your class decorator...

Comment: @JBernardo No, I don't think that would help.  I added more to the example code to be more clear.

Comment: Could you give us a better idea what is different between Class_A.from_A and Class_q.from_A?

Comment: @cwallenpoole There is no `Class_A.from_A`.  `Class_q.from_A` is conversion from `Class_A` to `Class_q`.

Comment: Ok, what is different between `Class_A.from_B` and `Class_A.from_C`

Comment: @cwallenpoole You may think of it as such: `Class_English.from_French` and `Class_English.from_German`.  All the `from_*` methods take an object and modify their internal state based on the type of the input and some other calculations.  All the `to_*` methods return new objects.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `to_*` methods aren't going to work because you need to explicitly include `self` at the beginning of the argument list to be able to use it in the method body. Secondly, I'd go with something akin to JBernardo's suggestion.

```
def to_class(self, cls):
    rt = cls()
    rt.from_class(self.__class__)
    return rt

def from_class(self, cls):
    #do stuff, with different things happening based on what class cls is; this may be a good place to use a dict of functions with the class or classname as keys
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot to include `self` in the `to_*`.  Does that change anything?  Also, I would like to avoid dictionary for performance reasons.

Comment: You think a dict is slower? It's not, that's how attribute lookup happens anyway.

Comment: @agf Thanks, I'm relatively new to Python, so I thought dict would be slower.